# is there any way to copy the rendered HTML of a div?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gmail, signature

I am working on a signature generator for emails and I want to copy the final signature with the press of a button instead of manually selecting the signature and copying it to the clipboard. This means I need the image, text and styling for them.

I have tried a couple of variants, including the w3schools one, but no success, some of them are only copying the text, but without the styling.

Example: https://www.mail-signatures.com/signature-generator/

Comment: All the styles would have to be inline. You do want to export HTML, right?

Comment: No, that's the catch. Gmail for example (but others too) use the rendered html format, not html code, this is why I need to copy and paste it.

Comment: I have the same question for the exact same purpose. My name is also Alex. What's going on?

Comment: Where would this button be? Do you mean you are building your own signature generator, or using the example and you want e.g. a browser extension to get the HTML?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please try the below code.

```js
function copyToClipboard(html) {
    var container = document.createElement('div')
    container.innerHTML = html
    container.style.position = 'fixed'
    container.style.pointerEvents = 'none'
    container.style.opacity = 0
    document.body.appendChild(container)
    window.getSelection().removeAllRanges()
    var range = document.createRange()
    range.selectNode(container)
    window.getSelection().addRange(range)
    document.execCommand('copy')
    document.body.removeChild(container);
    alert("Copied")
}

document.querySelector('button').onclick = function () {
    var htmlEditor = document.getElementById("html");
    copyToClipboard(htmlEditor.innerHTML)
}
```

```html
<button>Copy</button>
    <div id="html">
        <!-- The HTML you want to copy -->
        <table style="width: 525px; font-size: 11pt; font-family: Arial, sans-serif;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" fgid="15712">
            <tbody fgid="15718">
                <tr fgid="15724">
                    <td width="125" style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; border-right: 1px solid; border-right-color: #fb6303; width: 125px; padding-right: 10px; vertical-align: top;" valign="top" rowspan="6" fgid="15730">
                        <a href="https://www.my-company.com/" target="_blank" fgid="15736"><img border="0" alt="Logo" width="105" style="width:105px; height:auto; border:0;" src="https://codetwocdn.azureedge.net/images/mail-signatures/generator-dm/bease-fox/logo.png" fgid="15742"></a>
                    </td>

                    <td style="padding-left:10px" fgid="15749">
                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" fgid="15755">
                            <tbody fgid="15761">
                                <tr fgid="15767">
                                    <td style="font-size: 10pt; color:#0079ac; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; width: 400px; padding-bottom: 5px; padding-left: 10px; vertical-align: top;" valign="top" fgid="15773">
                                        <strong fgid="15779"><span style="font-size: 11pt; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color:#fb6303;"  fgid="15785">Sohail Ashraf</span></strong>
                                        <strong style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size:11pt; color:#000000;" fgid="15793"><span  fgid="15799"> | </span>Sales &amp; Marketing Director</strong>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr fgid="15808">
                                    <td style="font-size: 10pt; color:#444444; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; padding-bottom: 5px; padding-top: 5px; padding-left: 10px; vertical-align: top; line-height:17px;" valign="top" fgid="15814"> <span fgid="15820">        <span style="color: #fb6303;" fgid="15827"><strong fgid="15833">a: </strong></span> </span> <span fgid="15842">     <span style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size:10pt; color:#000000;"  fgid="15849">My Company</span>                                        </span> <span fgid="15858">     <span style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color: #000000;"  fgid="15865"><span  fgid="15871"> | </span>Street, City<span fgid="15879"></span></span> <span style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color: #000000;"
                                            fgid="15886"><span  fgid="15892"> | </span>Zip Code, Country</span>
                                        </span> <span fgid="15902"><br fgid="15908"></span> <span fgid="15915"><span style="color: #fb6303;" fgid="15921"><strong fgid="15927">e:</strong></span><span style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color:#000000;"
                                            fgid="15934"> john.doe@my-company.com</span></span> <span fgid="15942"><span  fgid="15948"> | </span><span style="color: #fb6303;" fgid="15955"><strong fgid="15961">w:</strong></span><a href="http://www.my-company.com"
                                            target="_blank" rel="noopener" style="text-decoration:none;" fgid="15968"><span style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color:#000000;"  fgid="15974"> www.my-company.com</span></a></span>
                                        <span fgid="15982"><br fgid="15988"></span> <span fgid="15995"><span style="color: #fb6303;" fgid="16001"><strong fgid="16007">m:</strong></span><span style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color:#000000;"
                                            fgid="16014"> (800) 555-0299</span></span>
                                        <span fgid="16022"><span  fgid="16028"> | </span><span style="color: #fb6303;" fgid="16035"><strong fgid="16041">p:</strong></span><span style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color:#000000;" fgid="16048"> (800) 555-0199</span></span>

                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr fgid="16056">
                                    <td style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-top: 5px; padding-left: 10px; vertical-align: bottom;" valign="bottom" fgid="16062">
                                        <span fgid="16068"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/MyCompany" target="_blank" rel="noopener" fgid="16074"><img border="0" width="19" alt="facebook icon" style="border:0; height:19px; width:19px" src="https://codetwocdn.azureedge.net/images/mail-signatures/generator-dm/bease-fox/fb.png" fgid="16080"></a>&nbsp;</span>
                                        <span fgid="16087">
                                                    <a href="https://twitter.com/MyCompany404" target="_blank" rel="noopener" fgid="16093"><img border="0" width="19" alt="twitter icon" style="border:0; height:19px; width:19px" src="https://codetwocdn.azureedge.net/images/mail-signatures/generator-dm/bease-fox/tt.png" fgid="16099"></a>&nbsp;</span>
                                        <span fgid="16106">
                                                        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/MyCompanyChannel" target="_blank" rel="noopener" fgid="16112"><img border="0" width="19" alt="youtube icon" style="border:0; height:19px; width:19px" src="https://codetwocdn.azureedge.net/images/mail-signatures/generator-dm/bease-fox/yt.png" fgid="16118"></a>&nbsp;</span>
                                        <span fgid="16125">
                                                            <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/mycompany404" target="_blank" rel="noopener" fgid="16131"><img border="0" width="19" alt="linkedin icon" style="border:0; height:19px; width:19px" src="https://codetwocdn.azureedge.net/images/mail-signatures/generator-dm/bease-fox/ln.png" fgid="16137"></a>&nbsp;</span>
                                        <span fgid="16144">
                                                                <a href="https://www.instagram.com/mycompany404/" target="_blank" rel="noopener" fgid="16150"><img border="0" width="19" alt="instagram icon" style="border:0; height:19px; width:19px" src="https://codetwocdn.azureedge.net/images/mail-signatures/generator-dm/bease-fox/it.png" fgid="16156"></a>&nbsp;</span>
                                        <span fgid="16163">
                                                                    <a href="https://pinterest.com/mycompany404/" target="_blank" rel="noopener" fgid="16169"><img border="0" width="19" alt="pinterest icon" style="border:0; height:19px; width:19px" src="https://codetwocdn.azureedge.net/images/mail-signatures/generator-dm/bease-fox/pt.png" fgid="16175"></a>&nbsp;</span>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

`document.execCommand()` is deprecated.

With Clipboard API you can do the same in a very much simpler way:

```
try {
  const htmlCode = document.getElementById("html").innerHTML
  const blobInput = new Blob([htmlCode], { type: 'text/html' })
  navigator.clipboard.write([new ClipboardItem({ 'text/html': blobInput })])
  alert('Copied')
} catch (e) {
  alert(e)
}
```

Comment: I was using this yesterday no problem and today it stopped working for me without any errors, chrome updated to Version 110.0.5481.77 could there be a bug or how else can I check? Interestingly using `navigator.clipboard.writeText(location.href);` works just fine.